# How to find wherther the JAR file is Compatible with JAVA 8 ? Is thery any short way or tool to find it Out?

Tags: java, migration

I am updating my APP  from JAVA 6 to  JAVA 8..  I have 100+ jars in my  Web-INF lib folder whiich are required to run the applications. So i need to make up this jars to be compatiblle with JAVA 8 verission. Suggest the possible ways to find the solution for  this ..

Comment: I am updating my APP from JAVA 8 to JAVA 8 ???

Comment: Java is backwards compatible, so generally speaking you can leverage any pre-Java-8 binary in a Java 8 application. It's the contrary that wouldn't work. **Edit** updating from Java 8 to... Java 8 seems like a smooth operation though XD

Comment: thx for the correction

Comment: No issues. If jars are compiled with JAVA 6, then it will work with JAVA 8. Reverse case may leads to some issues. No need to check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes java is backward compatible. for your case it should just work fine , so just go ahead and solve if and as you see them .

But to answer your question, you  can't tell from the JAR file itself, which java version it has been compiled .

If you want to know this, download a hex editor and open one of the class files inside the JAR and look at byte offsets 4 through 7. The version information is built in.

See more details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file)